# Graph with 2 interacted continuous predictor vatiable

Tags: r, logistic, data-visualization, interaction, continuous-data

When using `glm(link=logit)`, I detected a significant interaction between two continuous predictor variables. How can I present the results visually using R?

Answer (score 2):

Show the univariate plot where several curves correspond to different levels of other variable. If you model was y=xz, you'd pick z=0,1,2...n; then show y=0, y=x, y=2x etc. on the same graph. In this case these would be lines with different slopes.

Answer (score 1):

One of many approaches in R

```
require(rms)
dd <- datadist(mydata); options(datadist='dd')
f <- lrm(y ~ pol(x1, 2) * rcs(x2, 3), data=mydata)
# quadratic in x1, cublic spline in x2 with 3 default knots
bplot(f, x1, x2)   # 3-d plot; bplot has several options
```